# TextBox Password mode filling itself

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, passwords

I have a website where the user enters a combinations of login and password to enter.
I have some other page where the user has the ability to change the password. 
I added there 3 textboxs in password mode (actual, new, and confirm).

The odd thing is that the first textbox is being filled automatically with the password that i enter on login and that is stored in Firefox. 
If i do this on IE (where i don't have the password saved) this doesn't happen.

Also, this issue completely solves itself if i change the mode on the textboxs.

Am i missing something here? I obvisouly don't want the password to be filled automatically which would take away the whole purpose of the textbox.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the **autocomplete="off"** attribute to any fields that you don't want the browser to fill out.

Answer (score 1):

Add `autocomplete="off"` as an attribute.